Derived tensor products and regular sequences
Let $R \to A$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings, and let $x\in R$ be an element (or a sequence of elements in $R$, if you prefer) that is both $R$-regular and $A$-regular. Then we have
$$
A\otimes_R^L (R/xR) \cong A/xA
$$
in $D(A)$ (the derived category of $A$-modules). But the both sides can be considered as objects of $D(R/xR)$. So I expect that the above isomorphism holds in $D(R/xR)$. Is it true?

Shouldn't the equivalence you write down exist in $D(A)$ at the first place and then you forget to $D(A)$?

It's exactly. I edited. Thank you!
